# Is `adjustResize` compatible with CoordinatorLayout with android:fitsSystemWindows="true"?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

Normally `windowSoftInputMode` set to `adjustResize` would cause a `RecyclerView` to be resized such that an `EditText` positioned beneath it would become visible above the virtual keyboard. However, when the same `RecyclerView`, `EditText` layout is placed within a standard `CoordinatorLayout` hierarchy with `fitsSystemWindows` enabled, like the one below, `adjustResize` appears to have no effect and thus the `RecyclerView` doesn't resize and the virtual keyboard ends up covering the `EditText` view

```xml
<DrawerLayout
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
  <CoordinatorLayout
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <!--NOTE: If `fitsSystemWindows` above is `false`
    `adjustResize` behaves as expected but doing so ruins
    the child views' ability to receive insets and display
    themselves beneath the `Status Bar`--> 
    <AppBarLayout
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
      <CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <Toolbar
          android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
      </CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </AppBarLayout>
    ...
  </CoordinatorLayout>
  <NavigationView
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
</DrawerLayout>
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated; I'm happy to provide follow-up details and / or screenshots as well

Comment: do you get a similar behaviour `LinearLayout` or any other `Viewgroup`?

Comment: When I use a `LinearLayout` or something other than a `DrawerLayout` or `CoordinatorLayout` `adjustResize` works as expected